# Node.js: Mongoose schema default rand-tokens are not random

Tags: node.js, mongodb, random, default, uid

I have a `UserSchema` like this and I cannot seem to generate unique random `activation_token`'s.

I am using `rand-token` for the generation. [Found here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rand-token).

```
 var UserSchema = new Schema({
        activation_token: {
            type: String,
            default: randToken.generate(64),
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            unique: true,
            sparse: true
        },
        first_name: {
            type: String
        },
        last_name: {
            type: String
        }
});
```

Seemed to work fine, but when running unit tests with Mocha, all of the `activation_token` fields were the same. I initially thought this had to do with time, since that is probably what is used to generate the tokens. It was possible that for each new document, the timestamp was the same, so I ran some tests with a function that generated about 30 tokens one right after the other, and they were *not* similar.

*Any ideas on what is going on here?*

Here are some examples of the problem:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "555dfd137c914edc1b41bbda"
    },
    "email": "oka@haek.io",
    "first_name": "Lenora",
    "last_name": "Aguilar",
    "date_added": {
        "$date": "2015-05-21T15:43:01.576Z"
    },
    "activation_token": "EyBNwu4vxOIXMzj7W5kVOeICfWwxfjXmHkz7ZPHLjkf0MU86QM2aIKNDyvI2YmTR",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "555dfd107c914edc1b41bbd6"
    },
    "email": "ediuki@mu.edu",
    "first_name": "Eugene",
    "last_name": "Green",
    "date_added": {
        "$date": "2015-05-21T15:43:01.576Z"
    },
    "activation_token": "EyBNwu4vxOIXMzj7W5kVOeICfWwxfjXmHkz7ZPHLjkf0MU86QM2aIKNDyvI2YmTR",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It makes sense that they would all be the same. You're calling `generate` once at schema definition time and you're feeding the *result* of that call to the mongoose schema definition, not the function itself. You could try something like this:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    activation_token: {
        type: String,
        default: function() {
            return randToken.generate(64);
        }
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        sparse: true
    },
    first_name: {
        type: String
    },
    last_name: {
        type: String
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid package, by example:

```js
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

const UserSchema = new Schema({
        activation_token: {
            type: String,
            default: uuidv4,
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            unique: true,
            sparse: true
        },
        first_name: {
            type: String
        },
        last_name: {
            type: String
        }
});
```

The UUID standar is designed for prevent collisions and generate only secure (prevent adivination) unique ids on same system.

Remember, `default` parameter is called as funcion when need generate a new document, if you set a called function you set a the static string for all new documents, for execute the same function for each new document need wrap into other function, by example:

```js
default: () => randToken.generate(64),
```

Error:

```js
default: randToken.generate(64),
default: uuid(),
```

Ok:

```js
default: () => randToken.generate(64),
default: uuid,
default: () => uuid(),
```

Answer (score -2):

```
npm install rand-token --save
```

install the node package,

```
const randtoken = require('rand-token');
```

import in to js file and generate token

`const a = randtoken.generate(256`);